# select & print multiple value from dropdown list

Tags: php, list, drop-down-menu

in this code how can selected  multiple value from dropdown list

```
<?php 


include ("connect.php");

$member_id = intval($_POST['sector_list']); 


if($member_id == 0) { 
    // Default choice was selected 
} 
else { 
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE MemberID = $member_id LIMIT 1"); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) { 
        // Not a valid member 
    } 
    else { 
        // The member is in the database 
    } 
} 
?> 

<form method="post" action=""> 
    <input type="hidden" name="sector" value="sector_list">  
    <select name="sector_list" class="inputstandard" multiple="multiple">  
        <option value="0">send to</option> 
        <?php  
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from members') or die(mysql_error());   

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            echo '<option value="' . $row['MemberID'] . '">' . $row['MemberName']. '</option>';  
        } 
        ?>  
    </select> 
</form>
```

assume  the drop down list contain on (a,s,d,f,g,h,j,)

users selects multiple value ( a,s,j)

output = a,s,j    not only j

> > > ???

Answer (score 3):

([PHP Manual explanation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.select-multiple))

Change the list's name to be an array (have [] at the end):

```
<select name="sector_list[]" class="inputstandard" multiple="multiple">
```

`$_POST['sector_list']` will be an array of all the chosen options

Answer (score 1):

Change name of the select to:

```
<select name="sector_list[]" class="inputstandard" multiple="multiple">
```

In your code you can get them like:

```
print_r($_POST['sector_list']);
```